# How to get rid of unchecked cast warning from results

Tags: java

How to get rid of unchecked cast warning while accessing results

```
PageableResponse pageableResponse = fooService.findByFromId(fId, pageable);

 warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
        List<Foo> foos = (List<Foo>) pageableResponse.getResults();
```

class definition

```
public class PageableResponse<T> {
    private T results;
}
```

Comment: How is `pageableResponse` (the variable, not the class) defined?

Comment: @Sören updated description

Answer (score -1):

> How to get rid of unchecked cast warning while accessing results

Well, don't do an unchecked cast, of course.

It helps to understand what an unchecked cast is: it's a cast that exists in the source code, but cannot exist in the bytecode, because the type isn't available to check against.

A checked cast is something like `Foo foo = (Foo) something;`: there, the compiler can insert a `checkcast` instruction to ensure that `something` is an instance of `Foo` (or `null`), and it will fail if it's not. It can do this because (I assume) `Foo.class` exists, that is, `Foo` is a *reifiable type*.

In particular here, the JVM can't check that something is a `List<Foo>` because there's no such thing as a `List<Foo>` at runtime: everything is just a `List`. So, you can check that something is a `List`, but you can't know if it's a `List<Something>`, because there is no `List<Something>.class`.

You can't even do it by checking that all of the elements are instances of `Something` (or `null`): that doesn't actually tell you if it's a `List<Something>`; you can only know whether it's a `List<? super Something>`; and you can only know *that* if it's non-empty.

If you proceed with the unchecked cast, what the compiler is saying is that it can't guarantee that that the things in the `List` are of the right type. It allows you to proceed, but it's now at your own risk.

What you can do is to copy the things into a new list, where *you* are specifying that it's a `List<Foo>`, and check that everything in the results is of the right type when you do that copy:

```
List<Foo> foo = pageableResponse.getResults().stream().map(Foo.class::cast).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will throw a `ClassCastException` if anything in the list is not a `Foo` (or `null`).

This has the downside of creating a copy of the list. Assuming you're doing something like iterating the list, an alternative avoiding the copy would be to perform a cast before you use each element:

```
for (Object result : pageableResponse.getResults()) {
  Foo foo = (Foo) result;  // Will fail if not a Foo.

  // ...
}
```

The downside of this is that you have to consider the failure atomicity (i.e. how do you deal with a non-`Foo` after you have processed one or more `Foo`s - do you need to "undo" the prior processing etc).